# I can't decide if this is a rayleigh or poisson distribution

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, rayleigh-distribution

So here is the distribution it are certain events of time spent behind your telephone. I just can't decide which distribution it follows. I have thought about Poisson or Rayleigh.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your data or a way to generate the data?  What are the moments of your distribution?  Have you tried a qq plot against poisson and rayleigh?  There are few statisticians who can look at a distribution and pick between alternatives.

Comment: Start by telling us whether the observations are integers or groups of real numbers

Comment: The data are integers